# a mistake met in pthread_create

Tags: c, linux, gdb, pthreads

There is a mistake when I was running the code step by step, using `gdb` in Linux, that this happens.  After `(gdb) s`, 
I got these messages:

```
__pthread_create_2_1 (newthread=0x7fffffffdcc0, attr=0x0,
start_routine=0x400cdf <sendMessage>, arg=0x7fffffffdcd0)
at pthread_create.c:472
472 pthread_create.c: No such file or directory.
```

I used "`gcc -pthread -Wall -o`" to build and link my C source file and NO error happened except some warnings.
I have no idea how to deal with it.

[image]

Comment: @AlterMann `-pthread` is correct.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What were you expecting to happen after you typed `s`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no problem here.

You started your program, and you set a breakpoint just before calling `pthread_create`, so the debugger paused there.

Then you tried to step *inside `pthread_create`*. The debugger is fine with this.

The debugger knows that `pthread_create` is defined on line 472 of `pthread_create.c` - however, it doesn't actually have a copy of `pthread_create.c`. So it lets you know that it can't display the source code, which is what this message means:

```
472     pthread_create.c: No such file or directory.
```

You may want to use `n` (`next`) instead of `s` (`step`) to skip over the `pthread_create` call.

Comment: thank you very much!   I'll try it now ~ ~

Comment: Got it ! Thank you so much ~ ~